# Mixed Content and I can't find the probelm

Tags: https, redirection, html5

I can not find the problem. I looked and looked i just do not see any http:// link on this page... 
The URL is Englsih-the

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.english-the-easy-way.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure favicon 'http://www.english-the-easy-way.com/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
Thank everyone...

Answer (score 3):

You can use your browser's network inspector to see what's sent securely or not. In this case the browser tries to get a favicon for your page via https://www.english-the-easy-way.com/favicon.ico but is redirected.

Here's a screenshot of Firefox's network inspector. See how the marked line does not have a green padlock against it.

[image]

The network inspector in Firefox is part of the Web developer tools. Other browsers have similar capabilities.

Comment: Thank you but  the problem is I can't find that code to change it.. Do you know how I can find that code.. I have looked and looked and can't find. it thank you.

Comment: Either create a favicon.ico file or [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321878/how-to-prevent-favicon-ico-requests) if you don't want to

Comment: I though it was favicon.ico , to prove that isn't I removed that line , and still have the problem maybe you got better information if you order by domain and than I found it.
one unlock domain (fonts.gstatic.com) the line in question was <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> changed it to https fixed the problem

Answer (score 2):

If the page does not link to a custom favicon URL using `<link rel=icon>`, most browsers will try to retrieve it from the default location `/favicon.ico` instead.

In your case, `https://www.english-the-easy-way.com/favicon.ico` returns a 302 redirect to the plain-HTTP version of your website.

```
> GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2
> Host: www.english-the-easy-way.com

< HTTP/2 302 
< location: http://www.english-the-easy-way.com
```

(In fact it looks like *any* requests for nonexistent files return the same 302 redirect instead of a normal 404 error. That's probably not a good idea.)

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little old, but I got here from Google and it did help me, but I think what I already know can help.

#### The Issue of Redirection

Anyhoo, to add to [user1686](https://superuser.com/users/1686/user1686)'s answer, that's a problem where a page on a https url asks for a resource, in this case, the favicon, which redirecting to a non-https url. This is an issue because, for security reasons, browsers will not allow this.

As user1686 says, in [Lisa](https://superuser.com/users/1075490/lisa)'s case, that happens because [their website](https://www.english-the-easy-way.com/) redirects every not found error (404) to a 302 redirect. Although user1686 says that's not a good idea, I think it's pretty common nowadays to have non-existing URLs redirecting to the closest URL, or sometimes to the index page, and, if you're doing maintenance of your website, you might make that a 302 (temporary redirection).

So, how to deal with that? Well, in her case, since her favicon.ico does not exist and that's the start of the problem, uploading the favicon will be enough. But if you're having problems where your `https://example.com/favicon.ico` is redirecting to `http://example.com/favicon.ico`, you might need to look at your redirecting settings, and where they are is going to depend on your server.

##### Apache

If you're using Apache, redirection settings are set in your `.htaccess` file, and, although you may have many of them, the relevant one will be the one in the root folder of your website (usually called `www` or `web`). Editing .htaccess is an art in itself, I recommend using [these](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/all/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-.htaccess-file) [resources](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html).

##### Nginx

If you're using Nginx, you are going to have to play with the main configuration files, probably using the `try_files` and/or the `location` directive. You can learn how to use them [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/). If you don't know where the main configuration file is, it's probably in `/etc/nginx`, `/usr/local/nginx/conf` ,  or `/usr/local/etc/nginx`.

##### IIS

If you use Microsoft's IIS, I'm guessing it will have to do with the URL rewrite .NET extension. You can find more about it [here](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).